# My Arduino via communication with my Raspberry Pi isn't outputting correctly?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial, stepper

I'm trying to test and send a variable from my Raspberry Pi to my Arduino to turn my Stepper Motor, but it's not turning as it would if I put in a variable into the Arduino code itself and turn.

Here is my code for the Arduino:

#include <AccelStepper.h>

```
AccelStepper stepper(1,7,6); // Defaults to AccelStepper::FULL4WIRE (4 pins) on 2, 3, 4, 5
void setup(){  
   Serial.begin(9600);
   stepper.setMaxSpeed(150);
   stepper.setAcceleration(100);
   stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);  
}

void loop() { 
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    int theta = Serial.read();
    double theta_to_pulse = theta/1.8;
  stepper.runToNewPosition(theta_to_pulse);
  //stepper.runToNewPosition(0);
  //stepper.run();
}

}
```

Then here is my Python code via Raspberry Pi:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)


while True:

   theta = 90

   ser.write(theta)
```

Can I ask for some guidance? The Stepper Motor turns a bit when I run the python code, but never to the full point.

Comment: it probably means that is already at the target angle. have you tried sending different angles? also you are sending all the time the same angle. Send it just once, you dont need that loop in your python code

Comment: I did, but it moved at a very small step. I then tried it within the Serial Monitor and it turned at a small distance and then bounced back unexpectedly

Comment: Have you tried moving the servo giving hardcoded angles and not using the serial port? is it correctly moving to those angles? so if in your arduino you do `theta= 90` is it moving corectly?

Comment: I have. I gave the motor an angle and it moved that many degrees manually. It works perfectly fine. I verified and uploaded the Arduino code, I plugged in the Raspberry Pi into the Arduino, and I have the motor dragging power from the source it worked on every time when I tested manually.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74464582/edit) your post to fix the syntax/indentation errors in your code.

Comment: Thank you, I just did

Comment: ok, then remove the ser.write from inside the loop and try to send different values from the raspberry to the arduino, and wait betwwen one value and the next

Comment: Okay I did that, and I tested the code with theta = 54, and the stepper motor moves only a hair each time I hit run on the Raspeberry Pi Python code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Python code you wrote is correct?
The code have syntax errors. There is nothing inside the loop. Do you get any exception?
It should be like this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)    

while True:    
    theta = 90    
    ser.write(theta)
```

Comment: Sorry, I simply copy and pasted from Discord and indented. But that's the exact code I'm working with. There are no errors on the python side. I'm actually having trouble with a bigger code I have and that was getting the errors, so I tested with this example code and it's not working to turn the motor.

Comment: you shouldn't use a loop, using a loop is sending the value over and over to the serial port. Send the value just once

Comment: Okay so what I have now for my Python code is Import Serial, then ser = serial.serial('/dev/ttyACM0, 9600), then theta = 54, then ser.write(theta) only. When I run the code, it still will not turn the motor to the degree angle